# SQL Server restore differential without original full backup

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, backup, restore

Here is the situation:  I had a full backup, and a differential backup.   I have restored the full backup into the database.  But accidentally lost that backup file.

Now I would like to apply the differential backup.  Normally you must restore from both the full backup, and the differential, without opening the DB for use (norecovery option).  However, we have opened the DB, but not made any updates.

We have made a NEW full backup, which should be identical the original full backup, except for at least the timestamp.  That is, SQL Server detects that the differential is not taken from exactly that DB with that full backup.

Is there any way to trick SQL Server into allowing a differential to work with  new full backup?  (I realize it is risky, but the data is important and willing to risk some errors.)

Is there any other way to get the updates out of the differential backup so they could be applied manually?  Is there any "decoder" for a differential backup file?  Any special recovery tools for this kind of situation?

Comment: Ask better here [dba.stackexchange.com](http://www.dba.stackexchange.com). SO is for programming cases.

Comment: restore it another database

Comment: You would need to restore from the base full backup with norecovery and then restore the differential backups and log backups etc. I think you are in a bit of a trouble here, Try looking up on some 3rd party tools maybe there is something out there to do what you are trying to do.